# How do I use a LIKE clause in a PDO prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a sql query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title Like "%:needle%"
```

When I query the MySQL db manually with this statement it works. But when I use it with PDO and with the same values for :needle as I queried manually It just returns an empty result set.

Does utf8 encoding affects the behavior of it?

Answer (score 21):

With PDO, this can be done like:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE :needle");
$needle = '%somestring%';
$stmt->bindValue(':needle', $needle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 8):

try like

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title Like :needle';

$prep = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$ret = $prep->execute(array(':needle' => '%'.$somestring.'%'));
```

Comment: this code will never work

Comment: @SMJobayerAlam Yes, now, after I fixed a sylly mistake in it. But 10 years prior id didn't

Comment: Great @YourCommonSense I appreciate the update. I have used it today for testing. I've left this comment in order to inform others that it is functioning.

Answer (score 2):

The '%' needs to be in the variable, not the statement.
Put the '%' in the variable, and you should be fine.

```
'SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title Like ":needle"'

$needle = "%$needle%";
```

Comment: this code will never work

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("select * from itens where nome LIKE :nome");
$nome = "%".$item->getName()."%";  
$sql->bindParam("nome",$nome);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! To make sure your answer is helpful to others in the future, could you add a bit of a description as to why how this code solved the issue?